# Generating multiple DOM elements from a single data point with D3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Suppose that I have data like this:

```
[{from: 3, to: 5}, {from: 1, to: 2}]
```

I'd like to generate the following SVG:

```
<svg width="100" height="100">
  <g transform="translate(0,0)">
    <rect x="0" width="5" height="5"></rect>
    <rect x="10" width="5" height="5"></rect>
    <rect x="20" width="5" height="5"></rect>
  </g>
  <g transform="translate(0,30)">
    <rect x="0" width="5" height="5"></rect>
    <rect x="10" width="5" height="5"></rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Basically, for every data point, I have to generate `to - from + 1` rectangles. This is how I started:

```
var width = 100;
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(10))
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

var svg = d3.select('svg').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', 100);
var row = svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append('g')
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) { return 'translate(0,' + i * 30 + ')';});
```

Now, how do I generate multiple rects for every data point with the chain syntax?

I know that I could do it like this:

```
var rects = row.selectAll('rect')
  .data(function(d) { return d3.range(d.to - d.from + 1);})
```

but I'd like to avoid creating useless arrays.

Comment: Your range idea is probably the best way to go, given d3 fundamentally generates dom elements one-to-one against data. I wouldn't be worried about any efficiency / garbage collection issues with an array of a few integers..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could iterate in the `append()` function and create your rects dynamically there:

```js
var data = [{from: 3, to: 5}, {from: 1, to: 2}, {from: 4, to: 9}];

var width = 100;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .domain(d3.range(10))
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width]);

var svg = d3.select('div').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width)
  .attr('height', 100);

var row = svg.selectAll('g')
  .data(data)
  .enter().append(function(d) {
    var rects = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'g');
    for (var i = d.from; i <= d.to; i++) {
      var rect = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'rect');
      rect.setAttribute('width', 5);
      rect.setAttribute('height', 5);
      rect.setAttribute('x', (i - d.from) * 10);
      rects.appendChild(rect);
    }
    return rects;
  })
  .attr('transform', function(d, i) {
    return 'translate(0,' + i * 30 + ')';
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm having trouble with nested data. If you have time, could you please take a look ([JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/jewicoxivo/edit?html,js))? The first line of the graph should have two runs of segments, but only one is shown. Some `g` groups are left empty! Admittedly, this happens with the `d3.range` solution as well, but I cannot explain why...